# Any way to insert HTML markup, or CSS, within a Creole page?

Tags: creole

Using BitBucket for a small repo and would like to also use their provided wiki (*which uses Creole*).

- Is there a way to insert a stylesheet to use?
- Is there a way to insert HTML?

Comment: Just bumped into the same issue, have some docs that are markup and their wiki will not take the generated HTML, it renders the tags as text. :P